# Trouble understanding the not:(:last-child) selector

Tags: html, css

I’m new to HTML/CSS and I’m having a bit of trouble understanding how the `:not(:last-child)` selector works.  I’ve read the explanation on MDN and it’s a bit over my head so I was hoping for a simpler explanation.  I’ve written this code to better illustrate my issue:

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.paragraph:not(:last-child) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="paragraph">The first paragraph.</p>
<p class="paragraph">The second paragraph.</p>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list_item">List 1</li>
    <li class="list_item">List 1</li>
    <li class="list_item">List 1</li>
    <li class="list_item">List 1</li>
</ul>

<div class="new_div">
    <p class="test123">Hello World!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The way I understand it the line, `.paragraph:not(:last-child) { background: #ff0000; }` should tell CSS to apply a red background to every element with the class “paragraph” *except* the last one.  The behaviour I should see is a red background applied to the first paragraph *and nothing else.*

However, CSS applies a red background to *both* paragraphs.  It’s almost as if CSS is classing the unordered list as a paragraph and treating *that* as the last child or something.  But I can’t see any reason why it would do that.

If anyone could explain how this behaviour makes sense I’d be very appreciative.  Please bear in mind I’m very much a beginner so ELI5 if possible

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close! Last child pseudo requires the count of items within a context, in your code you are saying all paragraphs but not limiting the set so the browser doesn't know which to style.

I've updated your code to contain the paragraphs in a div and now the last paragraph is not styled with a red background. I had not thought to put a pseudo in a not pseudo so I learned something too. :)

For example if you want to do the same with the unordered list you can do all unordered list li's or use the list class to isolate lists with that class for this style. This is because li's are counted intrinsically, which means the browser knows how many there are already.

```css
.container .paragraph:not(:last-child),
ul.list li:not(:last-child),
.new_div p:not(:last-child) {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p class="paragraph">The first paragraph.</p>
<p class="paragraph">The second paragraph.</p>
</div>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list_item">List 1</li>
    <li class="list_item">List 1</li>
    <li class="list_item">List 1</li>
    <li class="list_item">List 1</li>
</ul>

<div class="new_div">
    <p class="test123">Hello World!</p>
     <p class="test123">Hello World!</p>
</div>
```